# React DnD image preview bug in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, react-dnd

I'm having this problem that when i start dragging an object, the image preview is bigger than the drag object's normal size and its opacity decreases (I'm not using disconnected drag preview). By the way it works perfectly fine in chrome.
OS : windows 10 -
Firefox version: 79.0,
you can see the normal size vs dragging size in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niGil.png)

And this is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd';

const DragObject = ({objectdata}) => {
  const [dropped, setDropped] = useState(false);
  const [place, setPlace] = useState();

  const [{ isDragging }, dragRef] = useDrag({
    item: { id: objectdata.id, type: 'anything' },
    end: (item, monitor) => {
      const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
      if (item && dropResult) {
        setDropped(true);
        setPlace(dropResult.place);
      }
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
  const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1;


  return (
    <>
      <img
        ref={dragRef}
        src={objectdata.image}
        alt={objectdata.title}
        className="object"
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: (dropped
        && place) ? `${place.x}%` : `${objectdata.x}%`,
          top: (dropped
        && place) ? `${place.y}%` : `${objectdata.y}%`,
          width: `${objectdata.size}%`,
          objectFit: 'contain',
          zIndex: '7',
          cursor: 'move',
          opacity,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default DragObject;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to include as many code examples as possible so we can help you better. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the drag component's code.@Kars Does anyone have an opinion?

Comment: Hi @MinaFa did you manage to solve this? I have a similar error